# How do I make a stop after a run?

Tags: bash, npm

If I do a:

```
npm run script
```

Can I stop it with a stop?

```
npm stop script
```

Why I tried it and it does not work.

I know that with the combination of "`Ctrl + c`" I kill it, but I want to do it by command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
ps -ef | grep script | awk '{print $2}' | head -n1 | xargs kill -9
```

This command should find first process named `script` on the list of all unix processes created by all users and kill it by with using its `PID`.